# Alternative of CopyCStringToPascal() for 64 bit mode while building using osx 10.11 sdk

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, upgrade

Problem:
I need to upgrade my project from OSX10.5 -32 bit  to OSX 10.11 - 64 bit. While upgrading, I got errors (implicit decalaration of function "" is invalid in C99) for many functions which have been deprecated in OS X 10.11 SDK for 64 bit mode. Few of those functions are:

```
CopyCStringToPascal()
CopyPascalStringToPascal()
FSOpenResFile()
FSMakeFSSpec()
GetDateTime()
SecondsToDate()
BlockMove()
```

... and similar functions.

These functions come from OS SDK and latest SDK have put

```
#if !__LP64__ 
..
.
..
#endif
```

guards around their declarations in their header file.

One way is to write wrapper that calls new functions in 64 bit mode and old function in 32 bit mode. 
I was wondering if there is another short (and easy) way to proceed from here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your basic question: there are 64-bit supported replacements for some of those functions.

- Strings: Use `CFString` or `NSString`
- `GetDateTime()`: Look at `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` or the `NSDate` class
- `SecondsToDate()`: Look at `CFCalendar` or `NSCalendar`
- `BlockMove()`: Use `memmove()`

But, any Mac application using APIs this old probably dates back to the classic Mac OS days, and also uses APIs that will not be straightforward to replace with 64-bit available APIs. For example, the `FSSpec` data type and all functions using it are gone. QuickDraw, ATSUI, Open Transport, HIToolbox, Appearance Manager, and all GUI-related APIs are gone.

It would take a substantial rewrite to get an application using those APIs to run 64-bit on the Mac. As a first step, can you compile your app against the 10.11 SDK in 32-bit? And does it really *need* to be 64-bit, at least right now?

Comment: Thanks for answering, Brendan (It's my first question on stackoverflow).
Yes, i can compile my app against the 10.11 SDK in 32 bit mode. and since we have committed 64 bit version to our customers, we need to do it. 
I think Apple should not have completely removed old API for 64 bit. Lots of changes will be required to meet those new API format. Sigh!

Comment: Yeah, the lack of 64-bit Carbon was a big shock and pain for companies with big Carbon applications. Microsoft just released 64-bit Office for Mac a few months ago, and it took Adobe years to port all their apps to Cocoa/64-bit.